# Quick question about the definition of non-degenerate $*$-morphism $A \to \mathcal{L}(E)$.

Tags: definition, c-star-algebras

Consider the following definition in Lance's book on Hilbert $C^*$-modules. Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra.

[image]

How is $\alpha(a_i) x_i$ defined? Is this a function evalutation?  I.e. does one evaluate $\alpha(a_i) : E \to E$ in $x_i \in E$? Or is this some sort of multiplication? How does one multiply elements in $E$ and in $\mathcal{L}(E)$ which is the set of adjointable maps $E \to E$.

Comment: In the field of operator algebras, whenever an operator is next to a vector, one should take it to mean the operator **applied** to the vector.  Thus $\alpha(a_i)x_i$ is to be understood as $\alpha(a_i)\big(x_i\big)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each $\alpha(a_i)$ is a linear map from $E$ to itself, and $\alpha(a_i)x_i$ should be thought of as evaluation of the function $\alpha(a_i)$ at $x_i$.  The notation stems from linear algebra, where $\alpha(a_i)$ is treated like a matrix, $x_i$ is treated like a vector, and $\alpha(a_i)x_i$ is thought of as the product of the "matrix" $\alpha(a_i)$ and the "vector" $x_i$.